# Prevent decal from showing on inside of mesh

Tags: three.js

I'm looking at the example here: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_decals

If I shoot a decal on the lips, adjust the orbital controls minimum distance, and go inside the mesh, I can see the decal on the inside of the mesh. Is there a way to prevent this? I'm trying to use the decal for something else where it is not desireable to have the decal show on both sides. Since THREE.DoubleSide is not the default, I'm not sure how this is happening.

Comment: the lips of the head mesh are continuous, so it is the same side, the decal just wraps on it, shoot the decal and hide the head (in console `scene.remove(scene.children[5])`) to see what i mean

Comment: @DerteTrdelnik I did see the pretty cool effect of removing the source mesh after it is all splattered. Is there anyway to prevent the "mirror" of the png used for the decal mesh from showing?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your material, simply set which side (or both) you want the decal to appear on using THREE.DoubleSide, THREE.FrontSide (default) or THREE.BackSide. Look at the [material object](https://threejs.org/docs/api/materials/Material.html) for more info...

```
var decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    map: decalNormal,
    transparent: true,
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: false,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: - 4,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
```

Comment: Derte was correct that in this case, the mesh actually folds into itself. In my original question I noted that THREE.DoubleSide is not the default so it should not appear on both sides of the mesh.