# How do you set which side a decal displays on a THREE JS mesh?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to apply a decal to the outside of a mesh object using DecalGeometry. However, the decal appears on the inside of the mesh. I've tried rotation and position settings within the DecalGeometry, but can't seem to affect which side of the mesh the decal appears on. FWIW, the mesh is a custom OBJ model. My code is a bit extensive to post here, but you can view the issue [here](http://thrive-studios.com/YF3JS/36offshore_decal.htm). I have red BoundingBoxHelpers to help visualize the placement.

Answer (score 0):

The materials object has a parameter which allows you to designate the side(s) of the mesh on which it will display (thanks @j-t for posting this question [Prevent decal from showing on inside of mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37823981/prevent-decal-from-showing-on-inside-of-mesh?rq=1). My working code looks like this...

```
var decalMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    map: decalNormal,
    transparent: true,
    depthTest: true,
    depthWrite: false,
    polygonOffset: true,
    polygonOffsetFactor: - 4,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
```